# WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apiman

I'm trying to find the correct version of the source code for the API Manager 2.1.0.

Version of the apimgt package in APIM 2.1.0 pack is 6.1.66, But it cannot find in the Git repository.
Please provide the link for the correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.1.66

This is already there. But you won't get this in tag search on github.